# How to handle CheckBoxFor for string value in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html-helper

Hello I am trying to handle checkbox for a form where it can be checked or unchecked for the status of task completion. In my database I have taken data field of type varchar which is to be set Pending/Done whenever user check/uncheck the checkbox. Checkbox examples which I found is not fulfilling my need because they are set to separate class of collection of Elements but I don't want that.

> MyTblModel.cs

```
 [Table("tblToDo")]
public class ToDoModel
{
    [Key]
    public int SrNo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]        
    public virtual DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
}
```

> MyContext.cs

```
public DbSet<ToDoModel> ToDoList { get; set; }
```

I am accessing this in controller.

> HomeController.cs

```
Session["ToDoList"] = myContext.ToDoList.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

Now I just fail to understand how to access above given status in CheckBoxFor because it expects me to pass bool value which I don't get. I also want to know, the time I save my data how to pass checkbox status to table as Done/Pending.
Thank you.

Comment: Your `Status` property is `int` type. What `varchar` status are you talking about ?

Comment: Oops, actually I was frequently trying the different approaches so this was the result of that.:-)

Comment: If you will always have 2 statuses(open and closed)(which i doubt), use a boolean type (IsClosed), else use a Status table with records for your statuses and have a foreign key to that

Comment: Status table approach I can implement but I don't know how will I implement this in EF logic.

Comment: Just create a new table for status. Add a foreign key to your ToDo entity. seed the status values.

Comment: @Shyju can you plz provide me the above given solution...